# Writing over previously output lines in the command prompt with ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line

I've run command line programs that output a line, and then update that line a moment later.  But with ruby I can only seem to output a line and then another line.

What I have being output now:

```
Downloading file:
11MB 294K/s
12MB 307K/s
14MB 294K/s
15MB 301K/s
16MB 300K/s
Done!
```

And instead, I want to see this:

```
Downloading file:
11MB 294K/s
```

Followed a moment later by this:

```
Downloading file:
16MB 300K/s
Done!
```

The line my ruby script outputs that shows the downloaded filesize and transfer speed would be overwritten each time instead of listing the updated values as a whole new line.

I'm currently using `puts` to generate output, which clearly isn't designed for this case.  Is there a different output method that can achieve this result?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `\r` to move the cursor to the beginning of the line.  And you should not be using `puts` as it adds `\n`, use `print` instead.  Like this:

```
print "11MB 294K/s"
print "\r"
print "12MB 307K/s"
```

One thing to keep in mind though: `\r` doesn't *delete* anything, it just moves the cursor back, so you would need to pad the output with spaces to overwrite the previous output (in case it was longer).

By default when `\n` is printed to the standard output the buffer is flushed.  Now you might need to use `STDOUT.flush` after `print` to make sure the text get printed right away.

Comment: This solution doesn't show output until either a newline is output, or the program ends, it seems.  This example, for instance `print '123';sleep 5; print "\r"; print "456"` does not print anything out at first, and then prints out "456" 5 seconds later.  So it doesn't help me much.

Comment: Add `STDOUT.flush` to send it to the output immediately.  I updated the answer as well.

Comment: "This solution doesn't show output until either a newline is output, or the program ends" That is a deliberate design decision in OSes, to buffer writes to use the I/O channels more efficiently. Sometimes we need the data to write immediately, hence the ability to force a flush using `flush`. A better solution for an application like yours which wants all STDOUTs written immediately, is to use `STDOUT.sync = true`. Buffering will be disabled for STDOUT removing the need to use `flush`. If you want to reenable buffering, set that back to `false`.