# How to code "press key to continue"

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement a simple "Press any key to continue". I print this message to the console, and I want to erase it after a key is pressed.

Following "[Writing over previously output lines in the command prompt with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762843/writing-over-previously-output-lines-in-the-command-prompt-with-ruby)", I tried this piece of code:

```rb
def continue
  print "Press any key to continue\r"
  gets
end

puts "An awesome story begins..."
continue
puts "And ends after 2 lines"
```

However, the `\r` trick doesn't work and the next `puts` won't erase the sentence. Is it because of a different function context? The `gets` spawns a newline? Or because I'm on Windows OS?

Comment: Btw StackOverflow syntax highlighting made me realize `continue` was a syntax keyword but apparently this is not a problem

Comment: Ruby does not have a `continue` keyword.

Comment: @Stefan Oh, then it was just SO's default coloring, as continue is used in several other languages... thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Instead of overwriting the previous output, you can also use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), e.g. `print "press key"; STDIN.getch; print "\e[G\e[K"` (`ESC [ G` moves the cursor to the first column and `ESC [ K` clears the remaining line)

Comment: @CyrilDD: Ruby uses `next` instead of `continue`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use STDIN from the IO class, rather than `gets`.

```
require 'io/console'                                                                                                       
def continue_story                                                                                                               
  print "press any key"                                                                                                    
  STDIN.getch                                                                                                              
  print "            \r" # extra space to overwrite in case next sentence is short                                                                                                              
end                                                                                                                        

puts "An awesome story begins..."                                                                                          
continue_story                                                                                                                   
puts "And ends after 2 lines"
```

This has the added bonus that it only requires one character to be entered (`getch` - get character) allowing the 'press any key' to work without a return or enter.

Comment: It isn't necessary to add "Edit:" lines. We can see what's been changed if necessary. Simply make your change where you would have added the information in the first place.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because you can't exit from the script with "ctrl+c" SIGINT or any other method if you need to interrupt during "STDIN.getch". If you use this in a loop or anything like that, there is no way to stop the script that you are running.