# Quick way to wait/sleep a program until a key is pressed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am writing a code where it is automated after the user interacts with the site, I currently have it on a 30 second timer (**sleep(30)**) where the user can interact for 30 seconds and the the automated code happens. Is there a quick ruby gem that I can use to delay / sleep the code until say the "r" key is pressed by the user.

Comment: This question seems to misunderstand on a fundamental level how web apps work.

Answer (score 0):

The `gets` method will halt execution until the user enters input:

```
loop do
 if gets.chomp == "r"
    # ... do what you need when the key is pressed
    break
  end
end
```

The user will have to press return to submit their input though. If you don't want to require the return button to be pressed, you can use something like `STDIN.getch` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34594382/2981429

Comment: Im more wondering if there is a way to unpause a program while on a webpage with a hotkey instead of using a gets with a terminal.